# How to generate Java-code from model of EMF

Tags: eclipse-emf, model-driven-development

I created a model with EMF and generated an Eclipse plugin for this model.
In the plugin I can now define an instance of that model. But now I want do generate Java-code from this instance. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first create a GenModel from you eCore Model. New -> Create -> EMF Generator Model -> From eCore -> Select you eCore. Then click on the top-level element of this model and pick Generate All.

**EDIT:**
There is not way to **directly** generate Java from custom model. You have to use JET, Accelo or xTend2 to write you generator. Or, you can probably take a look at xText project.

Comment: That's what I have already done, but I want to generate code from the model I have created with the generated plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open .genmodel file, then right click on top element and choose "Generate Model Code". It should generate java code for your model classes in directory defined in .genmodel. You can change various option in .genmodel just check its elements properties. [image: see screenshort]